# How to call web service and parse json in sencha?

Tags: android, json, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, cross-platform

Hello everyone i am working on sencha application where i need to call the web service in the click of button and i need to parse json.

I had google this a lot but not get any step by step tutorial . I am very new to sencha need a step by step tutorial for calling web service and parse json in sencha touch.

I also tried some code which is below :

My function:

```
    getDetails: function(){

               alert("Hi Welcome To Sencha");
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://www.aswaq.se/web_ajax_disp.php?fid=100&n=rt&p=rt',
                        params: { method: 'Helloworld', format: 'json' },
                        success: function (response, request) {
                            alert('Working!')
                            alert(response.responseText)
                            console.log('Response:-' + response.responseText)
                        },
                        failure: function (response, request) {
                            alert('Not working!')
                            console.log('Response Status:- ' + response.status)
                        }
                   });
        }
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

a simple and direct answer to your question would be :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.aswaq.se/web_ajax_disp.php?fid=100&n=rt&p=rt',
    params: { method: 'Helloworld', format: 'json' },
    success: function (response, request) {
        alert('Working!')
        var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    },
    failure: function (response, request) {
        alert('Not working!')
        console.log('Response Status:- ' + response.status)
    }
});
```

But sencha touch 2 and extjs guidelines reccomend to use [stores](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store):
It looks something like this:

```
 var myStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
    model: "User",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url : "/users.json",
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            rootProperty: "users"
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

When you load the store it will automatically call the right url specified in it and load the data inside according to the model you specified (model:User).
There are 2 ways you can use to load stores:
set autoLoad:true like in example and let the store load when its loaded in your app
call myStore.load() when you want